# SharePoint custom error pages and login issues

Tags: sharepoint, iis-7, custom-error-pages

I am currently trying to implement custom error pages in our SharePoint project.

Here is the issue I have: The custom error pages are set up in IIS. I'm using the .Net error pages in ISS7 for the error code 500. I also use the standard IIS error pages for the error codes 404 and 403.

This works fairly well as they do redirect to the correct page which is a SharePoint page.

However, I have login issues when I setup it up like this. I keep getting login prompt even thoough my account is correct. When I remove all the error management described above it all works fine, no more login errors.

Thank you ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIS has page error traping in its settings which you can use.